# Gray background on scroll in a Cordova iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I'm working on a mobile app using Phonegap/Cordova.
I built the ipa file using Phonegap Build and installed it on my iPhone.

I noticed when I scroll up or down at the edges of the view (like iOS bounce scrolling), the whole **application view scrolls down** (or up) and a **gray background color appears**.

I tried finding if there's a CSS code for that, but no luck.
I'm guessing maybe its something related to view-port.

**Things to Consider:**
- I'm using Framework7 v3
- PhoneGap Build cli-6.5.0
- iPhone 6S Plus

***Screenshots of the issue:***

[image]

What can be done to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to to your `config.xml` and then run `cordova prepare`:

```xml
<platform name="ios">
   <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
   <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
</platform>
```